# Bash for loops on a remote server

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am attempting to run multiple commands via a bash script on a remote server. specifically, the for loop to be run on the remote server is giving me issues.  I suspect it is because I don't know how to properly escape characters or use $().

Below is the code.

```
ssh (user)@(server) <<EOF
sudo su - (username)
whoami
'for e in $(`ls -lrt /usr/jboss/jbosseap | awk '{print $9}' | grep multichannel`);
do
echo "$e";
done'
```

Removing user and server names for obvious reasons.  Just concentrate on the for loop.  when I run that for loop command line (without the $()) its works fine.  Just not sure how to nest it in a remote call.

Thanks very much for any and all help!

Comment: Quote the here doc terminator (`ssh user@host << "EOF"`) to avoid bash eating your `$(..)` and `$9` and `$e`. Then you can just put the code you want to run verbatim (without trying to escape it with single quotes like you appear to have done here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a complex script that you're trying to run over ssh you're going to be better off putting that script in a file and piping that file into ssh like:

```
cat remote_script.sh | ssh user@host
```

or:

```
cat remote_script.sh | ssh user@host sudo -u username
```

And now you don't have to worry about *N* levels of escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as below .

here file "list " includes your list of nodes and script should be present in all nodes

`for i in $(cat list ) ;do ssh   -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no   $i "/path/your_script" ;done`